# How to run command only when parallel processing is successful

Tags: bash, gnu-parallel

I am using parallel GNU to process thousands of files and the conversion is successful, I am unable to delete the processed file once it's done.

I know I can use `parallel --halt now,fail=1` to stop parallel when a command fails but that's not what I am looking for.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.wav" | parallel -j+0 ffmpeg -threads 0 -hide_banner -loglevel error -i {} -movflags use_metadata_tags -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 ./converted/{.}.mp3 && rm {}`

Thanks

I tried using `&& rm {}` as part of the parallel process but the file was not deleted.

Comment: If you include `--halt now,fail=1` perhaps you can replace `&& rm {}` with `; rm {}`? Obviously you would need to test this before applying it to your actual data

Comment: @jared_mamrot, I just tried that, unfortunately, it failed.

`find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.wav" | parallel -j+0 ffmpeg --halt now,fail=1 -threads 0 -hide_banner -loglevel error -i {} -movflags use_metadata_tags
 -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 ./converted/{.}.mp3; rm {}`

Unrecognized option '-halt'.
Error splitting the argument list: Option not found
rm: cannot remove '{}': No such file or directory

Comment: Try `find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.wav" | parallel -j+0 --halt now,fail=1 'ffmpeg -threads 0 -hide_banner -loglevel error -i {} -movflags use_metadata_tags  -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 ./converted/{.}.mp3; rm {}'`?

Comment: As @jared_mamrot suggests, put all the stuff you want done by **GNU Parallel** inside single quotes.

Comment: @jared_mamrot, that worked. Thank you. If you change the comment to an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One potential solution is:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -iname "*.wav" |\
parallel -j+0 --halt now,fail=1 'ffmpeg -threads 0 -hide_banner -loglevel error -i {} -movflags use_metadata_tags  -c:a libmp3lame -q:a 2 ./converted/{.}.mp3; rm {}'
```

(making sure to quote commands)